# Google Play Console и авторские права

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

суть проблемы:
пишу новое приложение для игры Apex Legends и называется оно "Apex Legends Helper".

выкатил первую версию недели 2 назад. она оооочень быстро прошла модерацию (в течении 48 часов).
начали пилить следующую фичу. вчера допилил, выкатил обнову, заодно подлили парочку новых скринов.

и вот тут начинается интересное
приходит письмо "обновление отклонено. претензии к авторским правам. место  - Title".
ну лан с вами... меняю название на "Helper for Apex Legends".

сегодня приходит опять письмо, и кроме Title там появляется еще и Hi-res icon (я так понимаю это они про лого прилаги).

как с этими нехорошими людьми вообще бороться? что мне делать с названием приложения, может кто знает как правильно составить название, чтобы и в поисковике находилась и Гугл голову не дурил?

да и как в целом опубликовать приложение связанное с чем-то популярным, но при этом не получить голове за авторские права?

Comment: Единственный вариант - убрать все упоминания чего-то популярного. Гуглу вы доказать ничего не сможете - вас в любой момент могут забанить роботы или индийцы из их ТП. Разные государства пытаются проводить законы, которые запретят банить просто так без объяснений, но это дело нескольких лет и не будет работать сразу во всех странах. Ну и конечно всегда есть вариант запросить письменное разрешение на использование материалов от правообладателя. Это сильно снизит вероятность бана от робота.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я просто смотрю похожие приложения для этой же игры. они спокойно живут и с названиями Apex Legends NAME, и картинки из игры.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб и как такой возможно, что сначала приложение пропустили с таким названием и иконкой, а сейчас не пускает обновления, которые НЕ затрагивали эти 2 вещи?

Comment: @Wlad, вы не получите внятного ответа, это тайна покрытая гуглом. Лучше запросите официальное разрешение на использование названия и скриншотов игры, и проблем не будет никаких.